GitHub pass values from one job to another without "needs"
I am creating a CICD pipeline using GitHub actions. Idea is that every merge request against the master branch would trigger to build an image with the IMAGE_SHA=${{github.sha}}
I want to deploy to development when the PR is approved and merged to main.
How do I pass the value of IMAGE_SHA from job build to deploy.
name: Build Images and Deploy to Development

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - gh-readonly-queue/master/** # Merge queue for main branch (skip linting; will be done on PR only)

    build:
        if: (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'opened') || startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/gh-readonly-queue/master/')
        name:  Build and Push to ECR 
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        outputs:
            image-sha: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short}}
        steps:
            - name: Generate Short GIT Commit HASH
              id: vars
              run: echo "sha_short=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

    deploy:
        if: (github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/master')
        name:  Deploy To Development 
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        # needs: build.  <----- CANT USE needs as build won't be triggered when the push happens. 

I don't want to use artifacts to store image.sha every time the build happens as artifact also use the same concept of "needs" to look for the artifact
 - name: Upload image-sha artifact
              uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
              with:
                name: image-sha
                path: image-sha.txt


The build job will run first. It will build and push to ECR an image with a tag equal to the short SHA.
The deploy job will run some time later. It may be hours or days later. It will run in a different workflow run. This run will have a different ID and will have a different record on the UI. There is no easy way to share a piece of information between two workflow runs. The outputs and environment variables are only available within the same workflow run.
By the time this PR is merged, there may have been other PRs raised and several other images pushed. There is no way to link current push event to the SHA that created the image.
However, there is an easy way to find what PR number was merged on this push to master. If you tag your images with a PR number, you can easily deploy an image that corresponds to current workflow's push to master.
You can use this commit pulls API to find PR number.
